# I get "The field 'Activity' contains the value 'Experiment' that is not in the list of supported values." when trying to create a task in ADO

Tags: azure-devops

I get "The field 'Activity' contains the value 'Experiment' that is not in the list of supported values." when trying to create a task in ADO

Tried to create task directly under user story and as a seperate non-linked identity. I also verified that existing tasks have Experiment as part of their setup. So what has been changed?

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the inherited process in Organization Settings and add the'Experiment' value to the Picklist items in the 'Activity' field.

[image]

[image]